# VB.NET - Key word is not supported: provider

Tags: vb.net

When I try to connect to AcessDB, I get the error

> "Keyword is not supported: provider".

When I try to change provider, I get another error. When I delete provider tag, I also get an error.

```
Dim Exists As Boolean = False
Dim ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Name\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\datagrid\datagrid\pokus.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
Dim connection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
Try
    connection.Open()
    Dim command As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM studenti"

    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
    If reader.HasRows Then
        Exists = True
    Else
        Exists = False
    End If
    reader.Close()
    command.Dispose()
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.Write(ex.Message)
Finally
    connection.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: `If reader.HasRows Then
Exists = True
Else
Exists = False
End If` — This can (and should!) be shortened to `Exists = reader.HasRows`.

Comment: www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: I already have connection string from this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always write wrapper classes for database connections, and I always recommend the same.

```
Dim sConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Name\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\datagrid\datagrid\pokus.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

Dim Conn As New OleDbConnection
Conn.ConnectionString = sConnectionString 
Conn.Open()

Dim sQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM studenti"
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sQuery, Conn)
Dim dt As New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)

Conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

[SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx), [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx), etc. are `SQL Server`-specific classes.  You can't use them to connect to MS Access.

The documentation for [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) makes this very clear:

> Represents an open connection to a ***SQL Server*** database.

Consider using the [OldDbConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) and related classes instead.

Comment: And how i can use it in ADO.NET?

Comment: OleDbConnection ***is*** an ADO.NET class.  It's just that, unlike the classes in the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace, it isn't database-specific.  But you can use it exactly the way you already have it in your code.  IT's just that you need to change the classes from SqlConnection, SqlCommand, etc.. to OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand, etc...

Comment: [.NET Framework Data Providers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08(v=vs.110).aspx)